# Tkinter with Object Oriented

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, listbox

I'm new with Tkinter module and i tried to use OOP with Tkinter. Mycode has no error but the Listbox widget has no output , here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
class Test:
   word = ""
   def __init__(seld , w):
       self.word = w.get()

   def Try(self):
       return self.word

win = Tk()
a = StringVar()
win.geometry("750x750")
l1 = Label(win , text = "Name").grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
e1 = Entry(win , textvariable = a).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)
t = Test(a)
b = Button(win , text = "Show" , command = t.Try).grid(row = 1 , column = 0)
lb = Listbox(win , width = 50)
lb.grid(row = 2 , column = 0)
lb.insert(1 , t.Try)
win.mainloop()
```

can someone help me ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you create your `t` object, you give I'm the value of `a` at the moment. So at the creation, the value of `a.get()` is an empty string, as the program juste started to run. You should try this :

```
from tkinter import *
class Test:
   def __init__(self , w):
       self.w = w

   def Try(self):
       return self.w.get()

win = Tk()
a = StringVar()
win.geometry("750x750")
l1 = Label(win , text = "Name").grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
e1 = Entry(win , textvariable = a).grid(row = 0 , column = 1)
t = Test(a)
b = Button(win , text = "Show" , command = t.Try).grid(row = 1 , column = 0)
lb = Listbox(win , width = 50)
lb.grid(row = 2 , column = 0)
lb.insert(1 , t.Try())
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you notice that `lb.insert(1, t.Try)` should be `lb.insert(1, t.Try())` instead.  However it still inserts empty string.